# Fail after submit ios app with Expo EAS ( ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support )

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, expo

I'm trying to publish my app to Apple Store with Expo and EAS build + EAS submit.

But after submitting my app with `eas submit -p ios` I get an email from Apple saying there is a problem with my app even though neither `eas build` nor `eas submit` throws errors.

My eas configuration:

```
"production": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "ios": {
        "image": "latest" <-- Change this to 'default' had no effect
      },
      "env": {
        "API_URL": ""
      }
    }
```

[Email with error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3urZ7.png)

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 1):

I only recreate the provision profiles in Apple Developer Account, and works.